# Exception in XmlSerializer for a Dynamic ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, expandoobject

I have a Class and in class there is a property type Dynamic List when i am calling serializing for same class then threw exception-

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have
>   an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their
>   inheritance hierarchy. System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject does not implement
>   Add(System.Object).

Class architecture -

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Property1{ get; set; }
    public string Property2{ get; set; }
    public string Property3{ get; set; }
    public string Property4{ get; set; }

    public List<dynamic> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(TestClass.GetType());

```
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, Obj);
             string xmlString=textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

List productList = new List();

```
        dynamic product1 = new ExpandoObject();
        product1.Name = "Name1";
        product1.Search = "Search1";

        productList.Add(product1);

        dynamic product2 = new ExpandoObject();
        product2.Name = "Name2";
        product2.Search = "Search2";

        productList.Add(product2);

        dynamic product3 = new ExpandoObject();
        product3.Name = "Name3";
        product3.Search = "Search3";

        productList.Add(product3);

        TestClass obj = new TestClass();

        obj.Property1 = "p1";
        obj.Property2 = "p2";
        obj.Property3 = "p3";
        obj.Property4 = "p4";
        obj.ProductList = productList;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializeraa = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializeraa.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
            string xmlStringOut = textWriter.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(textWriter);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use a model class instead of dynamic for serialization, since the type need to be defined for dynamic.

All I did was assign proper values to every property and changed the TestClass.GetType() to obj.GetType() and print the textWriter. Please check below code :

**The ModelClass :**

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

**The TestClass :**

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }

    public List<ModelClass> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

**The Class to execute the Program :**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ModelClass> productList = new List<ModelClass>();

        var product1 = new ModelClass();
        product1.Name = "Name1";
        product1.Search = "Search1";

        productList.Add(product1);

        var product2 = new ModelClass();
        product2.Name = "Name2";
        product2.Search = "Search2";

        productList.Add(product2);

        var product3 = new ModelClass();
        product3.Name = "Name3";
        product3.Search = "Search3";

        productList.Add(product3);

        TestClass obj = new TestClass();

        obj.Property1 = "p1";
        obj.Property2 = "p2";
        obj.Property3 = "p3";
        obj.Property4 = "p4";
        obj.ProductList = productList;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
            string xmlString = textWriter.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(textWriter);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks .but I my case Product List has properties its not a string list.
Please check my answer

Comment: @amethianil Do you still face the exception?